# Disable Document Parsing for a Given Site Collection (Not Entire Web Application) - SharePoint 2013 On-Premises

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem

Is it possible to disable Document Parsing for a given SharePoint 2013 on-premises site collection so that I do not have to disable it for the entire web application the site collection resides within?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the parser on `SPWeb` objects via `SPWeb.ParserEnabled = $false`.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms what I was gathering from my reading of the formal MS articles. I was surprised, however, that the examples were often (if not exclusively) dealing with with the root site of the farm (e.g., [http://portal.contoso.com](http://portal.contoso.com)). Even Bill Baer's [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2014/08/29/document-property-promotion-and-demotion-overview-and-considerations.aspx) on the Document Parsing failed to mention (unless I missed it) that the ParerEnabled setting exists for each SPWeb, which could, of course, be a site collection.